# Checking if all radio buttons are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a common class `gender` for all the inputs. Then  i compare if they not checked, and alert empty. How can i properly check if all the buttons are checked?

```js
$( ".btn" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault;
if(  !$('input .gender').is(":checked") ) alert(" empty");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input class="gender"  type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="male"> Male<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="female"> Female<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="other"> Other<br>
<br><br>

<input class="gender"  type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="PHP"> PHP<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="Pyhon"> Python<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="Java"> Java<br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense, because you cant check/mark all radios of a same name at same time...

Comment: yuo mean if each group is checked?

Comment: no, if all radio buttons are checked

Comment: @GragasIncoming That is not possible.... That ain't how radio buttons work.

Comment: i mean if both groups are checked (2 radio buttons should be clicked) one on each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd select the checked radio buttons, and then verify that their length is equal to the number of radio fields:

```js
$( ".btn" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length !== 2) console.log("at least one is empty");
  else console.log('pass')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input class="gender"  type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="male"> Male<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="female"> Female<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="other"> Other<br>
<br><br>

<input class="gender"  type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="PHP"> PHP<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="Pyhon"> Python<br>
<input class="gender" type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="Java"> Java<br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

(preventDefault is a function that needs to be run, not a standalone property to declare.)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected , use below option of checking all checkboxes whether checked or not

```
$( ".btn" ).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault;
  var checkboxList = $('.gender')
  var isEmpty = true

$.each(checkboxList,function(i,v){
  console.log("is "+v.value+" checked -->"+v.checked)
  if(v.checked){
    isEmpty = false;
  }
})

  if(isEmpty){
    alert(" empty");
  }
});
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dmzMgo?editors=1011

**Explanation:**

$('.gender') retrieves all checkboxes and looping it through $.each and checking each field whether checked or not.
Checking flag isEmpty and then alerting based on that